# Magento 2: Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method setWebsiteId()

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, rest-api, fatal-error, interceptor

I had created a custom API for customer registration in Magento 2.3. I am checking that the weather the customer is already registered or not with below code.

```
$email = $this->request->getParam('email');
$firstName = $this->request->getParam('firstname');
$lastName = $this->request->getParam('lastname');
$websiteId = $this->request->getParam('websiteId');

$customerFactory = $this->_customerFactory->getCollection();

/**
 * check whether the email address is already registered or not
 */
$customer = $customerFactory->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email);

/**
 * if email address already registered, return the error message
 * else, create new customer account
 */
if ($customer->getId()) {
    echo 'Customer with email '.$email.' is already registered.';  
} else {
    // code...
}
```

But I am getting the api error when i run in postman. When I checked the api log report it shows below error.

```
"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Customer\\Collection\\Interceptor::setWebsiteId() in \/var\/www\/html\/app\/code\/MyModule\/Customapi\/Model\/AppcustomerregistrationManagement.php:187\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: MyModule\\Customapi\\Model\\AppcustomerregistrationManagement->signup()\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#5 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Intercept' in '\/var\/www\/html\/app\/code\/MyModule\/Customapi\/Model\/AppcustomerregistrationManagement.php' on line 187"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection` class has no method `setWebsiteId`. If you want to filter customer collection by website id you must set `website_id` as a filter field:

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $customerCollection */
$customer = $customerCollection->addFilter('website_id', $websiteId)
     ->addFilter('email', $email)
     ->getFirstItem();
```

Or You can use the repository for that purposes:

Add `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` in the constructor, like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
 */
private $customerRepository;

/**
 * ObtainCustomer constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
```

Use that code inside your method:

```
try {
    $customerEntity = $this->customerRepository->get(
        $email,
        $websiteId
    );
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    // no customer
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
    // no customer
}
```

Comment: thanks @SiarheyUchukhlebau for looking in to my issue and providing me the correct way, it got me the registered customer data. Thanks alot...!!!